# YUI drag and drop not working on dynamically added li element

Tags: drag-and-drop, yui

I  have used YUI drag and drop code from here: https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/dd/list-drag.html

This works when the lists are added statically. But when i create new li elements from javascript dynamically, then the code below executes but it cannot detect dynamically added li elements.

```
var lis = Y.all('#manageUser ul li');
lis.each(function(v, k) {
    debugger;

    //console("7");
        var dd = new Y.DD.Drag({
            node: v,
            target: {
                padding: '0 0 0 20'
            }
        }).plug(Y.Plugin.DDProxy, {
            moveOnEnd: false
        }).plug(Y.Plugin.DDConstrained, {
            constrain2node: '#manageUser'
        }).plug(Y.Plugin.DDNodeScroll, {
            node: v.get('parentNode')
        });
    });
```

So could you please help me to find out how can i make it work on dynamic elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually working on the same thing!  I don't know exactly how to do it, but start here
http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/dd/delegate-drop.html.  Delegation seems to be the answer.